# Checking that a radio button by default if none are checked already php

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to set a default radio button if none are already checked.

$p['selected'] tells if one has previously been selected. I'm nearly there with the code below, but it always sets the first row as checked. I only want this to happen if none are checked. So basically I want to see if any are checked and if not, then set a default. It used php 5.2.

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach($options as $p): 
    if($p['selected']) { 
        $checked = "checked";
    } elseif ($i == 0) { 
        $checked = "checked";
    } else {
        $checked = '';
    } 
?>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="option" <? echo $checked;?> value="<?=$p['id'];?>" onclick="document.forms.basket.submit();"><?=$p['name'];?>
  </label>
</div>
<?php 
    $i++; 
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: Why all the `?><?php`

Comment: The problem is that regardless of whether one of the elements in the `$options` array is `selected`, the `$i == 0` condition _is always true_ during the loop.  You need to do a pre-inspection of the `$options` array, using something like [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to determine if any are selected.

Comment: $p['id'] isn't really relevant to this.. It's the id assigned to the option so that we know what's selected.
?><?php is more inexperienced coding

Comment: What are the contents of $options ?

Comment: Your code is nothing wrong I think ! Just fix this line `<? echo $checked;?>` into `<?php echo $checked;?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a "pre-inspection" of the `$options` to determine if any are set.  Otherwise, `$i == 0` will always happen in your loop, regardless of whether one of the options has been selected or not.

```
// Filters all elements of `$options`, and only returns those that have `selected` set and truthy
$has_checked = array_filter( $options, function( $p ) {
    return ( ! empty( $p['selected'] ) );
});

// Sets to boolean - true if any of the $options were checked, false otherwise
$has_checked = ( ! is_empty( $has_checked ) );
```

Then, in your loop:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($options as $p): 
    // move this here to simplify the if statement
    $checked = '';

    if($p['selected']) { 
        $checked = 'checked';
    // only set in this case if $has_checked is false
    } elseif ( ! $hash_checked && 0 === $i++ ) { 
        $checked = 'checked';
    } 
....
```

Which *could* be combined to be like so, if desired:

```
    if($p['selected'] || ( ! $hash_checked && 0 === $i++ ) ) { 
        $checked = 'checked';
    }
```

And, you can remove the `$i++` from the end of your while loop.

**UPDATE for very old versions of PHP (older than 5.3)**
OP is using PHP 5.2, which doesn't support anonymous functions (became available in 5.3).  Below is the workaround:

```
// Filters all elements of `$options`, and only returns those that have `selected` set and truthy
$has_checked = array_filter( $options, 'has_checked' );

function has_checked( $p ) {
    return ( ! empty( $p['selected'] ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I need, but I missed some vital data.. It's using php 5.2 so get unexpected T_FUNCTION for $has_checked = array_filter( $options, function( $p ) {

Comment: I can't stress enough that you should not be on PHP 5.2 - you should be on _at least_ 5.6, and be planning to go to 7.x as soon as you can.  PHP 5.2 is so old, it's not even represented on the version history chart: http://php.net/supported-versions.php  - it's end of life, not supported, which means there are no security fixes being released for it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a workaround for pre-PHP 5.3

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you very much. It is running on cloudlinux so should have most, if not all security fixes applied to it.. It will be moved before long though.